# How do I order fields using an ORACLE select when my strings can contain wildcard characters

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g, wildcard

I have the following ORACLE table and data:

```
create table test_table (field1 varchar2(20));

insert into test_table values ('aaa.bbb.ccc.dd');
insert into test_table values ('aaa.bbb.c*c.dd');
insert into test_table values ('aaa.bbb.ccc');
insert into test_table values ('aaa.b*b.ccc');
insert into test_table values ('aaa.bbb');
insert into test_table values ('a*a.bbb');
insert into test_table values ('aaa');
insert into test_table values ('bbb.ccc.dd.ee');
insert into test_table values ('bbb.ccc.dd');
insert into test_table values ('bbb.ccc');
insert into test_table values ('bbb');
```

I'd like to do a table select which will retrieve the records in the following order:

aaa.bbb.ccc.dd
aaa.bbb.c*c.dd
aaa.bbb.ccc
aaa.b*b.ccc
aaa.bbb
a*a.bbb
aaa
bbb.ccc.dd.ee
bbb.ccc.dd
bbb.ccc
bbb

In my inserts above the records are obviously already in the right order but they won't normally be.

If I run the following select:

```
select field1 from test_table
order by field1;
```

I get the output:

a*a.bbb
aaa
aaa.b*b.ccc
aaa.bbb
aaa.bbb.c*c.dd
aaa.bbb.ccc
aaa.bbb.ccc.dd
bbb
bbb.ccc
bbb.ccc.dd
bbb.ccc.dd.ee

How do I write a SELECT statement to get my desired order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select field1
from test_table
order by  substr(field1, 1,1), replace(field1, '*', substr(field1, instr(field1, '*')-1, 1)) desc, instr(field1, '*') ;
```

Comment: This does not produce the required output, it produces:  FIELD1
--------------------  
a*a.bbb   
aaa   
aaa.b*b.ccc  
aaa.bbb  
aaa.bbb.c*c.dd  
aaa.bbb.ccc  
aaa.bbb.ccc.dd  
bbb  
bbb.ccc  
bbb.ccc.dd  
bbb.ccc.dd.ee  

11 rows selected.

Comment: @David: i have changed my answer, the query produces now the same  output you will retrieve in you question

Comment: schurik Thank you, I can award you the bounty tomorrow.